Efficiency-Focused thesis in Cancer Diagnosis Using AI (Advice Needed)
I'm looking for a topic for my master's thesis, I have an idea about focusing on efficiency in deep learning. I am thinking about investigating different methods (e.g knowledge distillation, pruning, quantization) that is used to make deep learning more light weight and fast. with lung cancer diagnosis or segmentation as an application. showing the results and its impact on accuracy and computational resources. and aim to evaluate the performance across different datasets (cross-dataset).
What do you think of the idea?
How can I structure my research to highlight this efficiency?
What experiments should I do?
Are there existing methods I should explore to enhance model performance without developing new models from scratch?
any suggestions on how to build value into my research!
